# run selfoss in a subsubfolder on an nginx webserver

Tags: nginx

I am trying to run [selfoss](http://selfoss.aditu.de) through nginx webserver in a subfolder of my home directory. The files are in `/home/me/web/selfoss`, and by the nginx instruction

```
location /me/ {
    alias /home/me/web/;
}
```

I can open it on the URL `myserver.com/me/selfoss` and see some of the content. But the browser can not find `all.css` and `all.js`, which are in another subfolder at `selfoss/public/`, so I set another nginx instruction [like said in the wiki](https://github.com/SSilence/selfoss/wiki/nginx-configuration)

```
location ~ ^/selfoss/(.+)$ {
    try_files /selfoss/public/$1 /selfoss/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

but this instruction seems to never match.

The me-instruction is in a file `me.conf` which is included in the server file in `sites-available` and the selfoss instruction is in another file `selfoss.conf` also included in the server file. I tried both including `selfoss.conf` as a sibling of `me.conf` and inside `me.conf`. No difference on both tries, `all.js` and `all.css` are not found.

What can I do?